# Horizontal CSS Wizard Navigation

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build up a horizontal css wizard navigation with a rounded css circle and text on each step. I am stuck on 1 point need to get ride on border from right side. Tried almost all steps. Attaching the code.

Attaching the screenshot of issue as well.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhx1T.png)

```css
ul {
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul:before {
  content: '';
  width: 96%;
  border: 2px solid #21a2d1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  margin-top: -6px;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: 16px;
}
.active:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #b7b7b7;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  margin-top: -6px;
  z-index: -1;
}
ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;  
}
li {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #21a2d1;
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: inline-block;  
}
.marker-number {
  font-size: 14px;
}
li.active {
  background: #04497b;
}
.active ~ li {
  background: #b7b7b7;
}
span.marker-text {
  color: #7d7d7d;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  width: 70px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: -21px;
  font-family: Arial;  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="marker-number">&nbsp;</span> <span class="marker-text">Select Car</span></li>
  <li><span class="marker-number">&nbsp;</span> <span class="marker-text">Questions</span></li>
  <li class="active"><span class="marker-number">&nbsp;</span> <span class="marker-text">Problems</span></li>
  <li><span class="marker-number">&nbsp;</span> <span class="marker-text">Inspection</span></li>
  <li><span class="marker-number">&nbsp;</span> <span class="marker-text">Solution</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a sample, using `flexbox`, with a minimal markup, and for the marker the `::before` pseudo and the line the `::after` pseudo (starting from the 2:nd position)

```css
ul.wizard, ul.wizard li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.wizard {
  counter-reset: num;
}
ul.wizard li {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
ul.wizard li::before {
  counter-increment: num;
  content: counter(num);
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #21a2d1;
}
ul.wizard li ~ li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  right: 50%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #21a2d1;
  top: calc(.75em - 2px);
  z-index: -1;
}
ul.wizard li.active::before {
  background: #04497b;
  color: white;
}
ul.wizard .active ~ li::before,
ul.wizard .active ~ li::after {
  background: #b7b7b7;
}
ul.wizard span {
  color: #7d7d7d;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/*  updated sample  */

ul.wizard li.completed::before {      /*  number and circle  */
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
ul.wizard li.completed span {         /*  text  */
  color: red;
}
ul.wizard li.completed + li::after {  /*  line after circle  */
  background: red;
}
ul.wizard li.completed::after {       /*  line before circle  */
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wizard">
  <li>
    <span>Select Car</span>
  </li>
  <li class="completed">
    <span>Questions</span>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    <span>Problems</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Inspection</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Solution</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

This can also be done without `flexbox`, if you need to target older browsers

```css
ul.wizard, ul.wizard li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.wizard {
  counter-reset: num;
}
ul.wizard li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.wizard li::before {
  display: block;
  counter-increment: num;
  content: counter(num);
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #21a2d1;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.wizard li ~ li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  right: 50%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #21a2d1;
  top: calc(.75em - 2px);
  z-index: -1;
}
ul.wizard li.active::before {
  background: #04497b;
  color: white;
}
ul.wizard .active ~ li::before,
ul.wizard .active ~ li::after {
  background: #b7b7b7;
}
ul.wizard span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #7d7d7d;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wizard">
  <li>
    <span>Select Car</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Questions</span>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    <span>Problems</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Inspection</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Solution</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @KunalVijan The rule `ul.wizard li.active::before` shows how to change color, simply add more rules for `ul.wizard li.completed::before` and so on. Or do you mean in some other way?

Comment: yeah but i have done like ul.wizard .active ~ li span,
ul.wizard .active ~ li span {
 color: #A8A8A8;
}

ul.wizard span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #00BFF9;

Comment: @KunalVijan Updated my first sample showing how to color number, circle and line ... check at the end of the CSS

Comment: thanks but if i adding a background color div on top of it, the border line is going back n removing z-index: -1 will bring the border line on top of cicrle as well

Comment: i have added ul.wizard li::before {
 display: block;
 counter-increment: num;
 content: '';
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 text-align: center;  
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: #00BCFA;
 margin: 0 auto;
 z-index: 1;
 position: relative; 
}

Comment: @KunalVijan I really don't understand what you are trying to do. If it is new requirements, please post a new question with images/explanation what you want to achieve in addition to what we solved here.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce width of pseudo element `:befor` to `90%` and `:after` to `45%` but you have to write it always different width percentages as per the activated `li` tag and as per screen size. I think If you modify your markup a little bit which will help you more and make the complications less.

============================================================

## Changed markup as you required and few tweaks in css

```css
ul {
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
     text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    padding-bottom: 20px; 
}
.marker-number {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #21a2d1;
  display: inline-block;
}
.marker-line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #21a2d1;
  top: 10px;
}
li.active span.marker-number,
li.active span.marker-line {
  background: #04497b;
}
.active ~ li span.marker-number,
.active ~ li span.marker-line {
  background: #b7b7b7;
}
span.marker-text {
  color: #7d7d7d;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: -15px;
     font-family: Arial;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>
  <span class="marker-number">&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="marker-line"></span>
  <span class="marker-text">Select Car</span>
 </li>
 <li>
  <span class="marker-number">&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="marker-line"></span>
  <span class="marker-text">Questions</span>
 </li>
 <li class="active">
  <span class="marker-number">&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="marker-line"></span>
  <span class="marker-text">Problems</span>
 </li>
 <li>
  <span class="marker-number">&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="marker-line"></span>
  <span class="marker-text">Inspection</span>
 </li>
 <li>
  <span class="marker-number">&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="marker-text">Solution</span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it would be very difficult to pick n set based on each element. code won't be dynamic in that case

Comment: Yea that's why I suggested. you have to make changes with your markup and then there will be no issue. You don't have to worry about the percentage and screen size.

Comment: Use the first ```span``` as a line or you can add a new ```span``` for the line no need to use the border styling. Once you will add ```span``` for line and write proper styling it will adjust it's width automatically. Also don't add ```span``` line for last ```li``` or you can hide it with CSS.

Comment: first span for line n no border thing

Comment: Try this made required changes to your markup and added CSS.